# Change option list text value based on <a> click

Tags: html, jquery, drop-down-menu, anchor, html-select

HTML

```html
  <select id="sel">
     <option>A</option>
     <option>B</option>
     <option>C</option>
     <option>D</option>
     <option>E</option>
   </select>

   <a href="#">A</a>
   <a href="#">B</a> 
   <a href="#">C</a>
   <a href="#" class="selected">D</a>
   <a href="#">E</a>
```

Here I created dropdown select option list( with options A, B, C, D and E) and some anchor tags with text values(A, B, C, D and E). My requirement is that when I click anchor tag whose class="selected"(i.e. one with text value D), the dropdown list should select option D. Note that text values of dropdown options are same as the text values of anchor tag. Please help me with jquery code

Comment: Please show us the jQuery code that you are using to do this. We can't help you find a problem in your code if we can't see it!

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for free code without any attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in jQuery,

```
$('.selected').click(function(){
   $('#sel').val($(this).text());
});
```

**PS:** You are expected to try before asking for help, and also post the code that you have tried.